# condition and loop: how can i don't resume the music when calling the function several times?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, conditional-statements, html5-audio

i have this function to play music with web audio API:

```
function playMusic(){

 if(countPre<count ){
    audio0.play();      
    audio0.src = '0.mp3';
    audio0.controls = true;
    audio0.autoplay = true;
    audio0.loop = true;
    source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    }
 else{audio0.pause();}

 }
```

However, the value of count and countPre are generated in a **loop** that runs 10 times per second.

I have to put the function playMusic **inside** that loop in order to update the values.

And here comes the problem:

I call playMusic 10 times per second! Every time, the music **resumes**.

I don't want it resumes, i want it plays **continuously** as long as the play condition is matched.

So is there any solution?

Comment: @Oskar Eriksson, what's the difference between web-audio and html5-audio?

Comment: The <audio>-element and Web Audio are different specifications. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-audio/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-audio/info are quick ways to understand the difference, at least here at stackoverflow. In real life it's fairly reasonable to include Web Audio in the term "HTML5 audio", though in you example you're using not using Web Audio at all.

Comment: Actually, your example does use Web Audio. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check that music is not already playing in your condition.

Don't think there's an audio method for that.
You can do it by many ways, example :

```
function playMusic(){

if(countPre<count && !this.is_playing ){
    this.is_playing = true;    
    audio0.play();      
    audio0.src = '0.mp3';
    audio0.controls = true;
    audio0.autoplay = true;
    audio0.loop = true;
    source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    }
 else{audio0.pause();
    this.is_playing = false}
 }
```