# What's the difference between web audio and html5 audio anyway?

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

I've just asked [a question about audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117654/condition-and-loop-how-can-i-dont-resume-the-music-when-calling-the-function-s), and people suggest that this is a question about html5-audio instead of web audio.

So i wonder what's the difference?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### These two concepts are different.

For example, the [**Introduction paragraph of the W3C proposed standard for Web Audio**](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#introduction) makes statements like
The introduction of the audio element in HTML5 is very important, allowing for ***basic streaming audio playback***. But, it is ***not powerful enough to handle more complex audio applications***.

Hence hinting at the difference between these two concepts:

**HTML5 Audio element** = basic playback by *embedding audio data in HTML*.

**Web Audio API** = An ECMA Script (JavaScript) based *API* to support audio capabilities comparable to these of a modern stand-alone PC, such as:

- mixing
- processing and filtering (e.g. cave or cathedral effects etc., distance attenuation, doppler shift etc...
- tasks related to audio production applications
- capabilities found in modern game audio engines

**A word of caution**: As of late October 2012, this API is still relatively new and not supported on all browsers and mobile devices.  [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/audio-api) site may be useful to determine the amount of support found for HTML5 and various related technologies on different platforms. The fact that W3C drafts standards for Web Audio is a strong indication that this API will, in time, receive universal acceptance and broad support, but this is not yet the case.